# Upper bound with additional constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have an expression $F(x)$ and I want to find an upper bound for $F(x)$, my result is such that

$$
|F(x)| \le C_1\exp(-\alpha x) + C_2
$$
where $C_1$, $C_2$ are the constants.
But I expect a result like that
$$ |F(x)| \le C\exp(-\alpha x) $$

My question is: is there a way to deal with $C_2$ to make the same rate as in the second inequality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help if you include the original expression for $F(x)$ which you are trying to bound, as well as what restrictions there are on $x$ and the constant $\alpha.$

Answer (score 0):

If your upper bound is meant to hold for positive $x$ (as it seems because of the $ \exp(-\alpha x)$ term, and I'm assuming $\alpha>0$) then unless $C_2 \le 0$ it cannot be done. For if $C_2>0$ the limit of the expression containing the extra constant $C_2$ as $x \to + \infty$ will be $C_2>0,$ while without the added $C_2,$ no matter what is chosen for $C$ in the second bound, it will be true that $C \exp( -\alpha x)  \to 0.$